# TypeError: myCanvas.getContext is not a function - .PDF implementation

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas

I am trying to implement a .PDF file to my website with mozilla pdfjs-dist.

This is my Script:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.0.943/build/pdf.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>

      <canvas id="addjob_pdf_preview"></canvas>

   </body>

</html>

<script>

     pdfjsLib.getDocument("PDFFILELINK").then(doc => {

        doc.getPage(1).then(page => {
            var myCanvas = document.getElementById("addjob_pdf_preview");
            var context = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

            var viewport = page.getViewport(1);
            myCanvas.width = viewport.width;
            myCanvas.height = viewport.height;

            page.render({
                canvasContext: context,
                viewport: viewport
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

It throws this error:

```
TypeError: myCanvas.getContext is not a function
```

I build the implementation exactly after this tutorial: [PDF.js Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZNeP7cjADo&t=322s)

I found a few threads about this topic, but im not able to understand what is wrong.

Some referred to the canvas API explanation: [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Which lead up to more questions than answers.

Regards

Comment: If you `console.log(myCanvas)` and inspect the result, do you see a valid canvas element?

Comment: you need the script within the HTML tag

Comment: @Al.G. - I added console.log("This file has" + doc.pdfInfo.numPages + " pages"); and got now this error: Cannot read property 'numPages' of undefined
    at pdfjsLib.getDocument.then.doc

Comment: Okay, the feedback in the console works. I had a typo in it. So the document gets loaded correctly, but it still gives me the error of the context back